# how to concate address with state in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to concatenate all address with state, suppose i've row with same state and different address so i want to run Query that will bring something as

```
    state      |  Address
    Maharastra    ABC,DEF,XYZ
    DELHI      |  WRU
```

currently my table is

```
  username | state      | Address
  abc         Maharastra   ABC
  abc         Maharastra   DEF
  abc         Maharastra   XYZ
  abc         DELHI        WRU
  def         Maharastra   ABC
  def         Maharastra   OVU
  def         GOA          IKL
  def         DELHI        WRU
```

what have i tried

```
   SELECT address,state from location where username='abc' GROUP BY state
```

and my output is

```
   address  state   
   ABC      Maharastra
   WRU      DELHI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is what you look for

```
SELECT STATE, GROUP_CONCAT(Address ORDER BY Address SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM location where username='abc'
GROUP BY STATE
```

Comment: Did you meant `GROUP_CONCAT(Address SEPARATOR ',')`? I've never seen commas used in it outside of its internal `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Addicted to Oracle. Followed the same syntax. Default separator is `COMMA`.